# ANGULARJS - display title inside h1 on homepage and div tag for the rest of the site

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

For accessibility compliance:

How do I display the title of the page inside an `<h1>` tag on the homepage, while display inside a `<div>` tag for the rest of the site.

I am using angular `UI-Router`, with the homepage having a state of `'home'`.

app.js:

```
magApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/404");

// Now set up the states
$stateProvider
    .state('page_404', {

        templateUrl: 'apps/templates/404.html'
    })
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'apps/templates/home.html',
        controller : 'issueController'
    })
```

I have tried:

```
<h1  data-ng-if="home" class="uwm-site-title">
  <a href="/">Site Name</a></h1>
<div date-ng-if="!home" class="uwm-site-title">
  <a href="/">Site Name</a></div>
```

I have also tried

```
<h1  data-ng-show="$state.current.name === 'home'" class="uwm-site-title">
   <a href="/">Site Name</a></h1>
<div data-ng-show="$state.current.name !== 'home'" class="uwm-site-title">
   <a href="/">Site Name</a></div>
```

Comment: some code examples wouldn't hurt

Comment: updated with example I have tried

Answer (score 0):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/qDWJx19WQB46MXDhNbxw?p=preview)

The native `UI-Router` solution would be driven by

- [Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)
- [Nested States and Nested Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views)

So, this would be our root html code snippet (index.html

```
<body> 
  ...
  <div ui-view="title">
    <h1>This is the default TITLE</h1>
  </div>

  ... // later more ui-view inlcuding unnamed ui-view=""
```

So, this view will for all the states at this moment showing the content: "`<h1>This is the default TITLE</h1>`". Other words, this state will show this content as is, because it does not work with named view **`ui-view="title"`**:

```
.state('home', {
      url: "/home",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
})
```

But there could be one state family, which will change it *(parent of it will, children will profit)*

```
.state('parent', {
      url: "/parent",
      views: {
        '' : {templateUrl: 'tpl.html', },
        'title@' : {template: "<h2>title for parent and its children family<h2>",}
      }
})
.state('parent.child', { 
      url: "/child",
      ...
})
...
```

Another state family could have different title:

```
.state('other', {
      url: "/other",
      views: {
        '' : {templateUrl: 'tpl.html', },
        'title@' : {template: "<h2>other family with this root has this title<h2>",}
      }
})
```

This could be repeated as many times. And even any child could declare its own title just by using the absolute naming for view targeting: **`'title@'`**

Some more info, how to use one root state for all children families *(later easy to apply some common stuff to all states)* [Angular UI Router - Nested States with multiple layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25667660/1679310)

More about absolute view naming - [Angular-UI Router: Nested Views Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29585103/1679310)

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qDWJx19WQB46MXDhNbxw?p=preview)