# AngularUI Router - Nested abstract routes not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm adapting a template called [Pages](http://pages.revox.io/) for an AngularJS app and I'm configuring nested view with the UI Router. It seems that everything is in place but the nested route "app/email" doesn't work, whenever it is called UI Router triggers "app/home" as the otherwise statement.

My code is this:

```
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider
            .otherwise('/app/home');

        $stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '/app',
                templateUrl: "tpl/app.html"
            })
            .state('app.home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: "tpl/home.html",
                controller: 'HomeCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load([

                            ], {
                                insertBefore: '#lazyload_placeholder'
                            })
                            .then(function() {
                                return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                                    'assets/js/controllers/home.js'
                                ]);
                            });
                    }]
                }
            })
            .state('app.email', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '/email',
                templateUrl: 'tpl/apps/email/email.html',
                resolve: {
                    deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                                'menuclipper',
                                'wysihtml5'
                            ], {
                                insertBefore: '#lazyload_placeholder'
                            })
                            .then(function() {
                                return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                                    'assets/js/apps/email/service.js',
                                    'assets/js/apps/email/email.js'
                                ])
                            });
                    }]
                }
            })
            .state('app.email.inbox', {
                url: '/inbox/:emailId',
                templateUrl: 'tpl/apps/email/email_inbox.html'
            })
            .state('app.email.compose', {
                url: '/compose',
                templateUrl: 'tpl/apps/email/email_compose.html'
            });

    }
```

Comment: seems like a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585103/angular-ui-router-nested-views-not-working

Answer (score 0):

An abstract state can have child states but cannot get activated itself. An 'abstract' state is simply a state that can't be transitioned to. It is activated implicitly when one of its descendants are activated.

check this [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#abstract-states) for more details about abstract in State Provider.

you can use email state as abstract like below code.

```
    .state('app.email', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '/email',
                template : '<ui-view></ui-view>'
    })
    .state('app.email.default', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'tpl/apps/email/email.html',
                resolve: {
                    deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                                'menuclipper',
                                'wysihtml5'
                            ], {
                                insertBefore: '#lazyload_placeholder'
                            })
                            .then(function() {
                                return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                                    'assets/js/apps/email/service.js',
                                    'assets/js/apps/email/email.js'
                                ])
                            });
                    }]
                }
            })
            .state('app.email.inbox', {
                url: '/inbox/:emailId',
                templateUrl: 'tpl/apps/email/email_inbox.html'
            })
            .state('app.email.compose', {
                url: '/compose',
                templateUrl: 'tpl/apps/email/email_compose.html'
            });
```