# How to load/render nested UI-Views in UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I have an application with one page called `index.html`. This page is the main page inside the application which I load my partials into.

Here is my `Index.html`:

```
<body>
    <!--<div id="view" ng-view></div>-->
    <div id="view" ui-view></div>
</body>
```

I want to load a Partial into this but then a partial into the partial i have just added.

The partial i want to add in is called `dashboard.html` and should be called when `/dashboard` routing is hit. Then I want to load a partial into the `UI-View` inside `dashboard.html`.

I don't know what other information I would need to supply to make this happen?

EDIT:

```
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'dashboard'
    })
    .state('dashboard.item', {
        //url: '/dashboard/calender',
        templateUrl: 'partials/calender.html',
        controller: 'aceTrackerDash'
    })
```

Comment: I've edited my answer my friend, take a look

Comment: My suggestion is to go through named views. Please provide html's code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its good to define nested states for this purpose . When the application is in a particular state — when a state is **"active"** — all of its ancestor states are implicitly active as well. Below, when the `"contacts.list"` state is active, the `"contacts"` state is implicitly active as well, because it's the parent state to `"contacts.list"` . So all nested defined views are loaded in their proper position:

**Example :**

```
$stateProvider
  .state('contacts', {
    templateUrl: 'contacts.html',
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.contacts = [{ name: 'Alice' }, { name: 'Bob' }];
    }
  })
  .state('contacts.list', {
    templateUrl: 'contacts.list.html'
  });
```

---

```
<!-- index.html -->
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

---

```
<!-- contacts.html -->
<h1>My Contacts</h1>
<div ui-view></div>
```

---

```
<!-- contacts.list.html -->
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
    <a>{{contact.name}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Plunker** : http://plnkr.co/edit/7FD5Wf?p=preview

**Also take a look at this :**

[Angular-UI Router: Nested Views Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585103/angular-ui-router-nested-views-not-working)

Comment: Thanks for the answer I have edit my question and added my router but this still does not appear?

Comment: @BenClarke I refer you to a more complete answer here in my answer