# How to remove base template from ui-view in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uiview

So I have this code:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        })

        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'DashboardController'
        })

        .state('customers', {
            url: '/customers',
            templateUrl: 'templates/customers.html',
            controller: 'CustomerController'
        })

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

Everything works but when I go to login, I still get the base template since I am using `ui-view`. How can I make the login state on his own? I mean without the base template where the ui-view resides.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29585707/863110) will help you

Comment: No idea what base template even is. Question is not very clear and neither is objective